# app crashes with no input while using Edittext in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-edittext

I am having this issue with Edittext in android studio.The app works fine but app crashes with no input

Here is the java code

```
public void onButtonClick (View v)
{
    int num1,num2,sum;

    EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
    EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2);

    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sum);

    num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());

    num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());

    sum = num1 + num2;

    t1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
}
```

Comment: Add the logcat please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt()` fails when no input is given, calculate only if there is an input.

```
public void onButtonClick (View v)
{
    int num1 = 0,num2 = 0,sum = 0;
    EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
    EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2);

    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sum);
    if(!(e1.getText().toString()).equals(""))
       num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
    if(!(e2.getText().toString()).equals(""))
       num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());

    sum = num1 + num2 ;

    t1.setText(sum.toString());
}
```

> Your application will crash if the given input is not a number.

**To make an EditText only accept numbers**

In the xml file use this

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789."
/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it now works great ... I don't have reputation sorry i can't vote your solution . @Uma Kanth